# How to dynamically add to a List<Object> in C#

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I have a Collection Class which is a class which puts a `List<Ingredient>` object, the contents of the Ingredient object list is displayed in a `CheckListBox` using binding.

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on one of the List items the information in that particular item is copied into another list called `List<Pizza> myPizza`, which will then display on the list. The reason I want all the data to go into it is because once in the `List<Pizza> myPizza` I will do more things to the data.

I have tried to do this but doesn't seem to work, below is the `CollectionClass`, the windows form and the Ingredient Class. I didn't bother putting the Pizza Class as it is the same as the Ingredient Class 
I know how to add it to the listbox using item, but I really want to add it to the List then add the List to the ListBox.

I hope this make sense, kind of new to programming. Thanks.

**Ingredient Class**.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //List<Ingredient> myIngredient = new List<Ingredient>();
    List<Pizza> myPizza = new List<Pizza>();
    CollectionClass myCollections = new CollectionClass();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myCollections.createList();

        checkedListBoxIngredients.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCollections.myIngredient, null);
        checkedListBoxIngredients.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
    }

    private void checkedListBoxIngredients_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Pizza pizza in myPizza)
        {
            checkedListBoxIngredients.Items.Add(pizza.ToppingName);
            checkedListBoxIngredients.Items.Add(pizza.UnitName);
            checkedListBoxIngredients.Items.Add(pizza.Cost);
            checkedListBoxIngredients.Items.Add(pizza.DescriptionName);
        }

        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            yourPizza.DataSource = new BindingSource(myPizza, null);
            yourPizza.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
        }
    }
}
```

**Ingredient Class.**

```
public class Ingredient
{
     public string ToppingName { get; set; }
     public string UnitName { get; set; }
     public int Cost { get; set; }
     public string DescriptionName { get; set; }

     public Ingredient(string pizzaToppingName, string pizzaToppingUnit, int pizzaCost, string pizzaDescription)
     {
         ToppingName = pizzaToppingName;
         UnitName = pizzaToppingUnit;
         Cost = pizzaCost;
         DescriptionName = pizzaDescription;
     }

     public string DisplayName
     {
         get
         {
             return ToppingName + " $"+Cost;
         }
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return ToppingName;
     }

  }
```

**CollectionClass.**

```
public class CollectionClass
{
    public List<Ingredient> myIngredient = new List<Ingredient>();

    public void createList()
    {
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Cheese", "grams", 3, "grab cheese and sprinkle on top of pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Olives", "grams", 2, "cut up olives and sprickle on pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Ham", "grams", 1, "spread cut up ham over pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Pineapple", "grams", 1, "spread cut up chunks over pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Pepperoni", "pieces", 1, "place slices on pepperoni on pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Onion", "handfuls", 1, "sprinkle cut up onion on pizza, try not to cry"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Peppers", "grams", 1, "sprinkle cut up peppers on pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Anchovy", "grams", 1, "place on top of pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Mushrooms", "grams", 1, "put gently on top of pizza"));
    }

    public void displayList()
    {
        foreach (Ingredient ingred in myIngredient)
            if (ingred != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ${2}.00, {3}",
                    ingred.ToppingName, ingred.UnitName, ingred.Cost,
                    ingred.DescriptionName);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you want to get the Pizza details of the checked item? And also where is the Pizza class?

Comment: Yeah I want to get all the details of the individual clicked item and Add them to the List<Pizza> myPizza.. I didnt add the Pizza Class because its exactly the same as the Ingredient Class.

Comment: You probably want a `List<Ingredient>` property in the `Pizza` class. Then you would add the chosen `Ingredient` to that list.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: So you have a `listbox` that each item is a `checkbox`, right? And which C# UI implementation did you use? WPF or WindowsForm?

Comment: I have a List<Object> binded to a CheckedListBox, and when one of the check boxes in the CheckedListBox is clicked it needs to send all the details from that individual item in that List to a second List, the second list will then bind to a ListBox.